# Transaction in middle of SQL Server Full bckup

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

If the full backup is started at 11 and completed at 4. at 2.30 there are some transaction happened. Will it be reflected on this full back up file?

Answer (score 2):

Check out these links from Paul Randal.

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-3030-backup-myths/
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/debunking-a-couple-of-myths-around-full-database-backups/
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/more-on-how-much-transaction-log-a-full-backup-includes/

Like many things in the database area, it all depends.

The last article is the best since it has the picture.  If the database read operation completed after the transaction, then part of the log will be in the backup.

The best way to recover to 2:30 is to do a point in time restore.

Restore the backup, any log files, and use the STOP AT command to get to the exact time you want.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179451.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are related to transaction log.
So after full backup , get a transaction log backup in order to be able restore database at a certain time.

Comment: That is true.  However, the backup may or may not have the transaction.  The best is to use both the FULL and LOG backups to do a point in time restore.

Comment: Yes the true backup strategy is this.